# The solution/solutions of Cases I and II is/are

Tags: grammatical-number

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

1. The solution of Cases I and II is ...
2. The solutions of Cases I and II are ...

Actually, I want to know whether we have to use a plural noun or a singular noun when the noun refers to two (or more) things.

Thank you

Comment: The answer is to determine whether you have a *single* solution (expressed in Cases I and II as a 'monolithic whole' or perhaps as 'parts') or *multiple* solutions (one in Case I and another in Case II). Neither singular nor plural serves as a universal answer.

Comment: *solution(s) **to***...

Comment: @Lawrence , There is one solution for Case I and one solution for Case II. I just need to say that the solution is a matrix for a mathematical problem. Should I still assume that "solution" is only one or more? 
Please clarify it.

Comment: One solution: singular. Multiple solutions: plural. The number of cases isn’t relevant in your question’s sample sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions, one of which pertains to case I and one of which pertains to case II. You therefore use the plural "solutions".

Try, "The solutions of Cases I and II are, respectively, [solution to Case I] and [solution to Case II]."

Comment: Thank you for your response. What about the following sentence?
1. The number of desks in Rooms one and two is ...
Or
2. The numbers of desks in Rooms one and two are ...

Comment: "Number" means "count" or "quantity" here. Again, whether you use the singular or plural depends on whether there are two counts or only one. In other words, if you are pointing out the number of desk in room one and the number of desk in room two, you use the plural because there are two distinct counts. If, however, you are pointing out the total count of desks between both rooms, you use the singular.

Comment: I didn’t grab your point. Would you please clarify it in complete sentences.

Comment: "The number of desks in rooms one and two is seven." This sentence means that there are seven desks in total between rooms one and two. "The numbers of desks in rooms one and two are four and three, respectively." This sentence means that room one has four desks and room two has three desks. Refer to my previous comment for an explanation of why this is.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I did totally understand. It was really important for me to grab this point.